# SignalR: Get clients list for PersistentConnection

Tags: vb.net, signalr

I searched google, SignalR wiki and SignalR code itself (for example, Broadcast function, Signaler and more), and found nothing.

I wrote ClientIDFactory and successfuly set ClientID to UserID.
It works, but now user cannot connect from more than one browser/tab.

I modified the function and added random string to the UserID. It works.

Now I need to find a way to get all connections for user(s), to send specific message to specific UserID.

I think about looping around client list, and find the UserID by string.split(), but other ways may be usefull.

I am not using Hub. only PersistentConnection.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need a list of clients? Can't you keep track of that list in your hub, when a new connection is made.

Comment: I am not using hub. I  can't using  OnConnectedAsync/OnConnected and track myself because on IIS AppPool Recycle (for example - code change), user "connected" with cookie from the old session, not fire this events. (and thanks for all)

Comment: Either way, you need to keep track of that yourself. A client can be on another machine and still get notified. It's really an implementation detail of the underlying message store and signal bus.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is not right hence this has surfaced. You have connect and disconnect method on server side to hook into. On Connection you need to persist connection with some meta data and then even if server restarts you can check meta data for unique user or unique client and reconnect them with new ID.

For example

1. If you are buying an item from mobile and you are not logged in (no meta data to relate to user) and you place 2 items in your basket. When you go on your desktop you wont see those two items in basket because server cannot relate to you as same user coming from same machine.
2. If you are logged in (meta data like email or username attached to current connection ID) and you browse from mobile and add 2 items in basket. When you login to your desktop (the new Connection ID can then be linked with same meta data email or userid) and then you can tell that its same user. If you then need to send a message to that user you have to send it to two client IDs which you can do by grouping them or sending it to two IDs.

If client lost connection ID it should be disconnected and on new connection it will have new connection ID so you should be thinking about mapping them.
If I connect with 7 IDs from 7 different mobiles notification would be sent to all 7 as long as your system knows that they are all intended recipient of this notifications. Implementation of persisting this knowledge is not part of signalR and so you have to implement it yourself.